# Schweizerisch oder Schweizer?

Tags: word-choice, adjective-ending

Ich selber würde mich wohl immer für den Schweizer Käse entscheiden, aber es gibt wohl auch schweizerischen Käse. Jedenfalls lese ich das aus diesem Google NGram.

[image: google ngram: schweizer, schweizerisch]

Wann ist welche Verwendung richtig?
Nicht nur in Bezug auf Käse, sondern allgemein.

Fügt man die korrekte [Groß- und Kleinschreibung hinzu](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Schweizerisch,Schweizer,%20schweizer,schweizerisch&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=) verliert das NGram an Aussagekraft, da die Häufigkeit von *Der Schweizer*, also der Verwendung als Subjekt, den Graphen verfälscht.

Comment: Ein ähnliches Problem taucht beim österreichischen Bundesland Steiermark auf. Hier gibt es die Adjektive "steiermärkisch" und "steirisch". "Steiermärkisch" wird verwendet um etwas amtliches oder offizielles auszudrücken: "steiermärkische Landesregierung", "steiermärkische Landesbahnen". "Steirisch" wird in allen anderen Fällen verwendet: "steirische Äpfel", "steirische Musik". Aus demselben Grund nennt man Menschen die in der Steiermark leben nicht "Steiermärker" sondern "Steirer".

Comment: `Ngrams not found: schweizerischen käse, schweizerischer käse`

Answer (score 10):

Das Adjektiv für Personen aus der Schweiz ist [*"Schweizer"*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schweizer_aus_der_Schweiz) und wird nach Duden großgeschrieben.

> *Schweizer Käse, Schweizer Uhren, Schweizer Bankgeheimnis, […]*

Mit [schweizerisch](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schweizerisch) wird etwas, was die Schweiz oder einen Schweizer betrifft, bezeichnet. Hier gilt zwar meist die Kleinschreibung, sobald aber *"schweizerisch"* Teil eines Eigennamens wird, kann es ebenfalls großgeschrieben sein:

> *Schweizerische Eidgenossenschaft, Schweizerische Volkspartei, Schweizerisches Bundesgericht, […]*

Answer (score 4):

Also meines Erachtens ist in den meisten Fällen "Schweizer" das korrekte Adjektiv.

So spricht man von Schweizer Uhren, Schweizer Schokolade und den Schweizer Banken (nicht immer nur positiv ^^)
Beispiele aus den Medien finden sich [hier](http://www.zeit.de/2012/40/CH-Uhrenindustrie-Schweiz-Wirtschaft) und [hier](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/spd-laender-wollen-schweizer-steuersuender-banken-lizenz-nehmen-a-874326.html).

Das Adjektiv schweizerisch wird vor allem dann gebraucht, wenn:

1. es sich um eine Gesellschaft, einen Verein oder eine andere Gruppierung handelt:

   > Schweizerische Eidgenossenschaft
   >
   > Schweizerische Rettungsflugwacht
   >
   > Schweizerische Volkspartei
   >
   > Schweizerisches Rotes Kreuz
   >
   > Schweizerische Lebensrettungs-Gesellschaft
2. betont werden soll, dass etwas als typisch schweizerisch empfunden wird,
   bzw. wenn auch etwas an den Nationalstolz appelliert werden soll.

   Beispiele wären:

   > die schweizerische Pünktlichkeit
   >
   > die schweizerische Neutralität

---

Sehr schön in diesem ngram zu sehen ist auch der massive Gebrauch von "Schweizerisch" während der Kriegsjahre.

Ich vermute, dies ist darauf zurückzuführen, dass während dieser Zeit das Wort "Schweizerisch" vermehrt auch in Propaganda verwendet wurde.

Dieses ngram zeigt das relativ schön:
[image: google ngram: schweizerische Neutralität]

Ein weiteres Ngram das dies verdeutlicht ist das ["Schweizerische Vaterland"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=schweizerische%20Vaterland&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=).

Answer (score 3):

Laut den *Schreibweisungen* der Schweizerischen Bundeskanzlei gibt es keine allgemeine Regel und kein erkennbares Prinzip, wann „Schweizer“ und wann „schweizerisch“ zu schreiben ist. Es wird empfohlen, sich am Sprachgebrauch oder an bestehenden Bezeichnungen zu orientieren.

Das gewöhnliche Adjektiv **„schweizerisch“** bedeutet „die Schweiz betreffend“, „die Schweizer betreffend“, „von den Schweizern stammend“ oder „zu den Schweizern gehörend“. Es wird grundsätzlich kleingeschrieben.

> schweizerische Besonderheiten
>   eine schweizerische Eigenart
>   die schweizerischen Landessprachen
>   schweizerische Varianten der deutschen Standardsprache
>   der schweizerische Wortschatz
>   schweizerische Ausdrücke
>   schweizerische Texte
>   schweizerische Ortsnamen
>   schweizerische Telefonnummern
>   die schweizerischen Lohn- und Arbeitsbedingungen
>   das schweizerische Recht
>   schweizerische Behörden
>   schweizerische Institutionen
>   die schweizerische Armee

Das Wort wird nur dann großgeschrieben, wenn es Bestandteil eines Eigennamens ist.

> die Schweizerische Eidgenossenschaft
>   der Schweizerische Bundesrat
>   die Schweizerischen Bundesbahnen
>   die Schweizerische Post
>   das Schweizerische Bundesgericht
>   die Schweizerische Bundeskanzlei
>   der Schweizerische Gewerkschaftsbund

Bei dem Wort **„Schweizer“** handelt es sich um eine Bildung aus der Einwohnerbezeichnung, die als nicht flektierbares Adjektiv verwendet wird. Wegen der Formgleichheit mit der Einwohnerbezeichnung ist die Großschreibung erhalten geblieben; d. h., „Schweizer“ wird immer großgeschrieben, auch wenn das Wort als flexionsloses Adjektiv vor einem Substantiv steht (siehe auch § 61 des Regelwerks zur deutschen Rechtschreibung).

> die Schweizer Armee
>   der Schweizer Käse
>   das Schweizer Messer
>   die Schweizer Uhren

Bestimmte Bildungen mit dem Wort „Schweizer“ werden (zumindest in schweizerischen Texten) zusammengeschrieben.

> Schweizervolk
>   Schweizerbürgerin/Schweizerbürger
>   Schweizerdeutsch
>   Schweizerfranken
>   Schweizerkreuz
>   Schweizerwappen
>   Schweizerfahne
>   Schweizergarde

In einigen Fällen können mit der Getrennt- bzw. Zusammenschreibung Bedeutungsunterschiede ausgedrückt werden.

> ein Schweizer Verein (irgendein Verein in der Schweiz)
>   ein Schweizerverein (ein Verein von Auslandschweizern im Ausland)

Answer (score 2):

Allgemein ist Schweizer Käse korrekt, da es meistens als Eigenname, bzw. Synonym für den Emmentaler verwendet wird. Ansonsten ist zwischen `Schweizer` und `schweizerischer` kein Unterschied, allerdings klingt Letzteres formeller.

/E: Oh, es scheint mir, als ob "schweizerisch" das offizielle Adjektiv ist.

Comment: Ups, ich habe mich wohl nicht deutlich ausgedrückt, mir ging es um die allgemeine Verwendung. _Edit:_ Frage angepasst. Für mich wäre _Schweizer Käse_ aber auch "normal" und richtig, weil es eben so im Käseregal steht. Aber das heisst ja nicht, dass es auch richtig ist.

Comment: Naja, *Schweizer Käse* ist halt einfach ein Eigen-/Produktname...