# "Bremer Bürgerschaft" oder "Bremische Bürgerschaft"

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context, regional

Das Landesparlament der Freien Hansestadt Bremen nennt sich "[Bremische Bürgerschaft](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremische_B%C3%BCrgerschaft)". Das klingt seltsam und unerwartet, da ich zuvor wohl fälschlich "Bremer Bürgerschaft" als die grammatikalisch richtige Form angesehen hatte.

Nun frage ich mich, warum diese Form die genutzte ist. Denn in der Wikipedia zum Beispiel heisst es nicht nur "Sie tagt im Haus der Bürgerschaft am *Bremer Marktplatz*" sondern sogar "Direkter Vorläufer der Bremischen Bürgerschaft war die Ernannte Bremische Bürgerschaft, ein nach dem Zweiten Weltkrieg eingesetztes Gremium zur Kontrolle *des Bremer Senats*, das von April bis November 1946 tagte. Die Tradition der Bremischen Bürgerschaft reicht bis ins 12. Jahrhundert zurück." Ebenso der "[Bremer Rat](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremer_Rat)"

Diese also zunächst wenigstens ungewöhnliche Form *scheint* wenig erklärungsbedürftig, da zwar eine einfache Erklärung dahinter stecken muss, diese aber kaum per Netzsuche zu finden scheint.

Zwar kämen die Erklärungen "reine Tradition" oder "Hat mit Hansestadt zu tun" leicht in den Sinn, zumal diese Konstruktion auch für die Hamburgische Bürgerschaft zu finden ist, aber das ist schlicht unbefriedigend.

Ist dahinter nicht vielmehr auch ein Bedeutungsunterschied zu finden? Also ein auch juristisch relevanter Unterschied? Ein Unterschied der allerdings nicht unmittelbar einsichtig wäre. So ähnlich wie in ["deutscher Kaiser" oder "Kaiser von Deutschland"](https://www.welt.de/kultur/history/article1139396/Wilhelm-und-das-Kaiserdrama-in-Versailles.html)?

Es scheint mir nun fast der Fall zu sein, dass *in* Bremen die Menschen von der "bremischen Polizei" reden, außerhalb der Stadt aber die selbe Menge als "Bremer Polizei" bezeichnet wird.
Wenn man hingegen die große Müllhalde fragt, nach zum Beispiel der ["Münchnerischen Bürgerschaft"](https://www.google.com/search?&q=%22m%C3%BCnchnerischen+b%C3%BCrgerschaft%22), dann ist die Trefferliste ziemlich dürftig.

Tradition, Regionalismus, aktuelle Präferenz, tieferer Bedeutungszusammenhang?

Also, warum heisst es "Bremische" statt "Bremer", und was hat das zu bedeuten?

Answer (score 4):

Laut [diesem](https://www.weser-kurier.de/bremen_artikel,-Bremisch-_arid,1494641.html) Artikel sind *Bremer* und *Bremisch* Synonyme, außer da, wo sie es nicht sind: In bestimmten stehenden Ausdrücken, in denen es *Bremisch* heißen muß, z.B.:

- Bremische Bürgerschaft
- der Bremische Deichverband
- die Bremische Evangelische Kirche

Hier gehört das *bremisch* jeweils traditionell zum Eigennamen.

Ähnliches scheint es auch in Berlin und Hamburg zu geben - dort gibt es den *Berliner Bären*, aber die Leute sprechen *berlinerisch* - wobei man dort wirklich nur den Dialekt meint, die *Hamburgische Bürgerschaft* gibt es auch. Genau dasselbe auch bei *Schweizer* vs. *schweizerisch*, deshalb ist in diesem Kontext auch [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5742/schweizerisch-oder-schweizer) relevant.

Comment: Hm. +1 für den unterhaltsamen link. Aber: Just one rule, there are no rules, but even that has exceptions? Und ist das auch für "Hamburgische" gültig?